# How to upload a json.encode string to firebase (or how to parse stream response for multiple iterations of one string)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, jsonparser

Until now, I have been uploading my firebase database as follows:

```
          try {
        _firestore.collection('activity').doc(docID).set({
          DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').format(dateTime): {
            'host-$listOfAcceptedPlayers': {
              'levels': [selectedRange.start, selectedRange.end],
              'listOfAcceptedPlayers': [listOfAcceptedPlayers],
              'numOfPlayers': '${_amountOfPlayers[_selectedPlayer]}',
              'time': [
                DateFormat('HHmm').format(dateTime),
                DateFormat('HHmm').format(endDateTime)
              ],
              // 'time_end': '${DateFormat('HHmm').format(endDateTime)}'
            }
          }
        }, SetOptions(merge: true));
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
```

Although because I am unable to parse the response from the server since it gives me a non JSON response (no ""), I am trying to update the way I upload my code to the following method:

```
 var bodyHost = {};
      bodyHost["time"] = [
        "${DateFormat('HHmm').format(dateTime)}",
        "${DateFormat('HHmm').format(endDateTime)}"
      ];
      // var numOfPlayers = {};
      bodyHost["numOfPlayers"] = "${_amountOfPlayers[_selectedPlayer]}";
      // var listOfAcceptedPlayers = {};
      bodyHost["listOfAcceptedPlayers"] = "$listOfAcceptedPlayers";
      // var levels =  {};
      bodyHost["levels"] = [
        "${selectedRange.start}",
        "${selectedRange.end}"
      ];
      var host = {};
      host["host-$listOfAcceptedPlayers"] = bodyHost;
      var date = {};
      date["${DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').format(dateTime)}"] = host;
      String str = json.encode(date);
      print(str);
      _firestore.collection('activity').doc(docID).set({str});
```

Although I am getting the following error The argument type 'Set' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. (Documentation). What is the right way to go about this?

If there is a way to parse the original response please let me know, just one thing to note - the "host-listOfAcceptedPlayers" will change every time I read it, and I want to capture what the listOfAcceptedPlayers is to then pull the data beneath it in the tree. The easiest way would be snapshot.data['levels'] (for example) although I cannot access the tree without knowing the listOfAcceptedPlayers (and how many/what the list of different emails would be).

Answer (score 1):

I actually found out a different way to do this. Using RegEx I am able to search for my user's email address and return that in the following list:

```
    var todaySnap =
    snapshot.data['04-24-2023'];
print(todaySnap);
var todaySnapStr =
    todaySnap.toString();
var regexp =
    RegExp(r"(?<=host-).+?(?=:)");
print(regexp.allMatches(
    todaySnapStr, 0));

final emailMatches = regexp
    .allMatches(todaySnapStr)
    .map((m) => m.group(0))
    .toList();
print(emailMatches[1]);
```

The host- and : are what separate my email address in my specific case.